# parellel.for loop - why doesn't this throw an error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I just converted the "CODE 1" to use "parellel.for" loop in "CODE 2" But why doesn't "CODE 2" run correctly?

> Error: "AmbiguousMatchExceptionUnhandled"

**CODE 1**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To 99

            sum = sum + i
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = sum

    End Sub
End Class
```

**CODE 2**

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer = 0


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Parallel.For(i, 99, k)

    End Sub


    Function k()

        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To 99

            sum = sum + i
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = sum

        Return Nothing
    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it may point out enough problems with the code for you to fix it.

Comment: That helped me to a certain extent, but not for this question of "parellel.for" but for some other :), By the way, it showed me that "implicit conversion from integer to string is prohibited" that's because I tried to get the value of integer to a string, but still the code runs fine with this alone "textbox1.text = sum" , but option strict shows to use "textbox1.text = CStr(sum)" .. Why is that both codes run without any problem of accuracy etc? does it slow down the program when I use "sum" only, instead of "CStr (sum) ?

Comment: Without Option Strict On, VB will try to convert types at run-time to make them fit. However, it won't necessarily select the conversion that you *intended*. It will often make code run somewhat more slowly.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Morton :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Function k()` doesn't accept an `Integer` parameter so its an unsuitable delegate for  `Parallel.For`.

Now, think about why the function needs to take a parameter, then think about why you are not going to get the results you expect. Even after you fix this first superficial issue.

Parallel means that all the cycles of the loop could run at the same time.

Comment: I still can't understand what you said, are you saying that I should use a "integer" type ? :) I saw somewhere that in-spite of what I used at "k" they had used this Sub(i) Dim temp As New Dummy(sNames(i)) lReturedVal = temp.Process2(lIntervalHolder(i * 2), lIntervalHolder(i * 2 + 1)) lTotal += lReturedVal End Sub) and I don't understand it either how should I amend that code to suite mine ? ? :/ –

Comment: Like this ? 

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        Parallel.For(0, 99, Sub(i)  sum = sum + i    End Sub) 
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(sum)
    End Sub